# Angular 2 array push not updating the view from a service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {AttachmentModel} from "../view-attachments/attachment.model";
@Injectable()
   export class AttachmentService {
   // Observable array sources
     private attachmentSource = new Subject<AttachmentModel>();

   // Observable array streams
   attachmentAdded$ = this.attachmentSource.asObservable();

   // Service commands
  addAttachment(attachment: AttachmentModel) {
     this.attachmentSource.next(attachment);
  }
}
```

and I call it from a component like so:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {AttachmentModel} from "./attachment.model";
import {AttachmentService} from "../services/AttachmentService";  

@Component({
   selector: 'view-attachments',
   templateUrl: './view.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  public attachments;
  public attachment: AttachmentModel;

  constructor(private attachmentService: AttachmentService) {
    this.attachments = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.attachmentService.attachmentAdded$.subscribe(
        attachments => {
            alert();
            this.attachments.push(attachments);
            this.attachments = this.attachments.slice();
        }
    );
}

handleGoogleFiles = (files) => {
    if (typeof(files) !== 'undefined') {
        for (let file of files) {
            this.attachmentService.addAttachment({
                deleted: false,
                resource_drive_file: file,
                resource_type: 'liveDrive',
                resource_drive_share_type: 'copy'
            });
        }
    }
 }
}
```

When I add an item to the service the alert fires as you would expect and so does the attachments.push.

However, the view is not updated until I click anywhere on the DOM and then any subsequent attachment additions show straight away.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you call `handleGoogleFiles`? Are you sure that it is executed within angular zone?

Comment: Within the view I've got a call to a directive as so: <app-google-drive-picker (filesAdded)="handleGoogleFiles($event)"></app-google-drive-picker> , this directive emits an event when a file is selected from Google Drive Picker, the method handleGoogleFiles successfully receives the data from this directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a this.zone.run(() => {}); to trigger a redraw of the page.

zone is defined as follows

public zone: NgZone

You do not alter the variable by itself but changing the content of the variable. Its still on the same place in memory. At this point the change detections fails sometimes.

Comment: I implemented it as follows: this.zone.run(() => { this.attachments.push(attachment); });

Comment: I would usually do it like
this.zone.run(() => { });
this.attachments.push(attachment);

Comment: More the other way around:

    this.attachments.push(attachment);
    this.zone.run(() => { });